# Every continuous function $f:ℝ\to ℝ$ can be presented as a sum of a certain power series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've encountered a statement that I am unable to prove or disprove:

> Every continuous function $f:ℝ\to ℝ$ can be presented as a sum of a certain power series.

Is this statement true? If yes, can somebody prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: The function $f(x) := |x|$ has no derivative at $x = 0$.  So, it cannot have a power series.  Yet, it is continuous.

Comment: And where did you encounter this statement?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't even true for smooth functions. The classic example: try to expand 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&x\ne 0\\
0&x=0\end{cases}
$$
in a power series at $x=0$. Convince yourself that $f^{n}(0)$ exists for any $n$ and is zero (these are the coefficients of a hypothetical power series). But the function certainly isn't zero in any positive radius of the origin.

Comment: but $f$ can be represented as a power series in each point of it domain regardless that $f$ is not analytic and it Taylor expansion around zero have zero radius of convergence.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Analyticity at a point requires a positive radius

Answer (score -2):

This is not true in all cases. Power series are differentiable almost everywhere but there exist continuous functions which are differentiable nowhere. Now consider the continuous smooth function $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ with $f(0)=0$. What power series would you like this to be equal to? You should find that the only power series it could be is: $0 + 0x + 0x^2 +\cdots$ but this function is not zero.

Comment: Almost everywhere?

Comment: I don't think it's really obvious that this function would not have a power series.  You might want to add details that explain that.

Comment: What exactly does "power series" mean? Does it just mean Taylor or Laurent series, or are more general series of powers also considered "power series"?

Comment: So can all functions which have infinite amount of derivatives be presented as above mentioned sum? I gather that if we take any polynomial with finite deg, then we won't be able to present it as sum of a power series. Am I right?

Comment: Power series means general series

Comment: @mrrobot1337 I'm sorry, I didn't understand your comment. What exactly are "general series"? What is the most general form for such a series? Is it something like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_nx+b_n)^{c_n}$ where $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are real constants?

Comment: A function series of a form  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n*x(x-a)^n$

Comment: power series are differentiable, at most, on the closure of it radius of convergence. This is a lot less than "almost everywhere".

Comment: @zhw. If one wants to be precise about where power series are differentiable, there needs to be a discussion of radius/annulus of convergence and what happens on the edge. By saying “almost everywhere” I mean “If I say everywhere then there might be a pathological counterexample depending on my memory and your definitions” rather than “except on a measure zero set”.

Comment: @Masacroso I suppose “within the radius of convergence” was something that I meant but didn’t say... it doesn’t really make much sense to try to differentiate a function where it isn’t defined.